# How to use boto3 without AWS Vault?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, boto

I have the following method that is working in Python:

```
def connect_s3_boto3():
    try:
        os.environ['AWS_PROFILE'] = "a9e"
        s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
        return s3
    except:
        raise
```

The issue is that works using `~/.aws/config`:

```
[profile home]
aws_access_key_id=ID
aws_secret_access_key=SECRET
[profile a9e]
region=eu-west-1
role_arn=DAROLE
source_profile=home
```

So, I've a set of doubts. In a production environment where I want to use that method, I need to set AWS Vault? There is no other alternative? For example using `IAM_ROLE` as in `boto2`.

Comment: I've used boto3 before in my Python code and it works. So long as your resource using that code (e.g: a Lambda) has the correct Role. So for your example above, if you were to run that in a Lambda it would fail - unless you gave the Lambda a role to use S3.

Comment: @Joe In that case I mean with an infrastucture with Jenkins, that every X time runs the script, not a Lambda function. So, how you assign that role?

Comment: If you are running scripts on an EC2 instance (say for example, Jenkins was installed on EC2 and was running scripts) - then that EC2 instance should have a role assigned to it which has the correct permissions to read/write to S3. You can create the role and permissions in the AWS Console under IAM. You can then assign the role to the EC2 instance in the EC2 dashboard from within the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For code running on an Amazon EC2 instance:

- Create an **IAM Role** and assign appropriate permissions
- Associate the role with an Amazon EC2 instance
- Any code running on the instance that calls an AWS SDK will automatically obtain credentials associated with the role
- There is no need to put Access Key, Secret Key nor Role in the config/credentials files

See: [IAM Roles for Amazon EC2 - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html)

If you are running code on a non-EC2 computer, then you will need entries in the config/credentials files. This will involve at minimum an Access Key and Secret Key associated with an IAM User. If you then wish to use an IAM Role, the code would need to `AssumeRole()` using those credentials.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @JohnRotenstein